# eric6 is not working in ubuntu14.10

Tags: python, pyqt5

I installed `Python` 3.4 and `PyQt` 5.4.1 and Eric 6 in Ubuntu 14.10.
When I type "sudo eric6", eric6 is not working!
Here are the errors. Please tell me what can I do.

```html
Error information:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2015-05-01, 00:42:31
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<class 'TypeError'>: 
QsciLexerPython(QObject parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Shell'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/eric6.py", line 326, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/eric6.py", line 323, in main
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/eric6.py", line 306, in main
    restartArgs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/UI/UserInterface.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.__createLayout(debugServer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/UI/UserInterface.py", line 620, in __createLayout
    self.__createSidebarsLayout(debugServer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/UI/UserInterface.py", line 853, in __createSidebarsLayout
    ShellAssembly(debugServer, self.viewmanager, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/QScintilla/Shell.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.__shell = Shell(dbs, vm, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/QScintilla/Shell.py", line 236, in __init__
    self.__bindLexer()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/QScintilla/Shell.py", line 308, in __bindLexer
    self.lexer_ = Lexers.getLexer(self.language, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/QScintilla/Lexers/__init__.py", line 209, in getLexer
    return LexerPython(language, parent)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/eric6/QScintilla/Lexers/LexerPython.py", line 31, in __init__
    QsciLexerPython.__init__(self, parent)
```

Comment: why sudo? Does it work without sudo?

Comment: it doesn't work without sudo ethier

Answer (score 0):

The bug report [here](http://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org:48888/issues/issue162) (and other reports linked from there) seem to indicate that the build of PyQt5.qsci in the repositories is behind that of PyQt, or that the current qsci is installed in the wrong place, and building from source should, in theory, fix it.

```
So finally, the simplest way to install Eric6 on Ubuntu 14.10 is :
#Install some dependencies
sudo apt-get install mercurial build-essential qt5-default
qtbase5-qttools5-dev-tools libqt5scintilla2-11 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit
python3-pyqt5.qtsvg python3-pyqt5.qtsql
#Build PyQt5.qsci from sources
sudo apt-get sources python3-pyqt5.qsci
cd qscintilla2-2.8.3+dfsg/Python
python3 configure.py --pyqt=PyQt5 -q /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake -d
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5
make
sudo make install
#Download and build Eric6 from sources
hg clone http://die-offenbachs.homelinux.org:48888/hg/eric
cd eric
sudo python3 install.py
```